# how to solve RecursionError with pyintaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I have created codes (a.py) about editing the csv file, just using some for loop and while loop, pandas loc function, etc.
but this codes should load a csv file in order to run.

when i  attempt to use `pyintaller` to pack this a.py to exe, 
it says:

> for field, value in iter_fields(node):
>   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

I am in Windows 10, python:3.6  pyinstaller:3.4.dev0+7817d3fac
to use anaconda prompt and input: `pyinstaller 'path'/a.py -F .`
is it because of the csv file is not referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a .spec file and setting a higher recursion limit.

Create the spec file by running:

```
pyi-makespec -F a.py
```

Then edit the .spec file to set the recursion limit by adding the following at the top:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(9000)
```

Finally, build your EXE by passing your spec file to pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller a.spec
```

Comment: After I modifty the spec file recursionlimit to 20000, it occurs another error:                              Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: C:/qt5b/qt_1524647842210/_h_env/Library/plugins

Comment: PyQt5 with PyInstaller is a whole different issue. In your spec file, you'll need to add " pathex=['env\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\bin' ", as well as " hiddenimports=['PyQt5.sip'] ".

Comment: Should I simply chage the variable panthex, or add another ? and before  'env\\' should I add driver d: or somthing?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully complete the process by installing PyQt5 which I conda list it found it existed 'pyqt', but acutally pyQt5 is not installed yet. So I pip install pyqt5 and succeed.